# How to set mysql user variable at every new connection in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

**Background:** We rely heavily on views in our app and one of the ways in which we are looking to optimize them is by parameterization.  We've got that aspect all figured out, but in order to make it work, I must be able to set a user parameter for the customer (tenant) id.  I want to do this at a base level so that it is set for every single connection.

For example the script I want to run is simply:
`Set @Param_CustomerId:=1234`
where `1234` is the customer id based on the authentication.

**Here's the question:** Where can I set up code that will get run every time a new MySQL Connection is established?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can run that code in the `registerConnectionServices` method of a class which would extend the default `DatabaseServiceProvider` (and use that extended provider instead of the default).